# How to create Android.mk

Tags: android

My requirement is : I have Exapmle1.c, Example2.c and corresponding Exapmle1.h, Example2.h files. Example2.c is called in Example1.c.

> How to create Android.mk.?

I have already created jni and Libs Folder and i put all files in that folder.

Comment: You are posting your name and phone number? Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this template

```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Refer given link :
 http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html